# How do I configure proxy on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: networking, proxy

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04, and with I've setup broadband connection, windows 7 allow all internet access, but Ubuntu 14.04 some application access via internet, I can't access Firefox browser and Terminal command line via internet, when running this application then showing me proxy setting... Any one help me, How do I configure proxy manually on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Synaptic Package Manager(you can search it from the top left most icon if you are not able to find it)

Then click on `Settings->Preferences`.

Then go to Network, choose manual proxy configuration and then apply after you have setup the proxy settings. It will work for you.

Comment: But http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/ here what username and password ?

Comment: Here you have to provide that username and password which are saved in the proxy server. If you doesn't know them you have to contact your administrator.

Comment: This broadband connection username & password same in the proxy server ? If not how I can setup this ?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get this working on Desktop? The link that Druid posted is from 2004, and I have not gotten it to work, although that could be user error rather than the fact that it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping that this link may help you  : http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-desktop-to-use-your-proxy-server.html

Or this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1575